# Unable to export project as WAR file in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I received this error during the export of WAR file for my project. Anyone can help here? Thanks!

```
org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException: Error exportingC:/Users/xxxxx.war
at 
org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.ComponentExportOperation.execute(ComponentExportOperation.java:150)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl$1.run(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:385)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:410)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:360)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.doExecute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:247)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.executeImpl(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:219)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.cacheThreadAndContinue(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:89)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.execute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:207)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.ui.DataModelWizard$1CatchThrowableRunnableWithProgress.run(DataModelWizard.java:220)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

Comment: which version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: There are several bugs filed in Eclipse regarding this. So use latest version preferably
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=306638
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=322536

Comment: i'm using Elcipse Juno Service Release 1 @Reddy

Answer (score -1):

Right click on a Web project folder and select Export from the pop-up menu. Then select WAR file in the Export window and then select Next.
Specify the Web project you want to export (this field is primed if you used the pop-up menu to open the wizard), and specify a location for the new WAR file
Optional: Optionally, supply WAR export Options, such as whether or not to include Java™ source files in the WAR, and whether to overwrite any existing resources during the export process. Source files are not usually included in a WAR file, because they are not necessary for the server to run the web application.
Click Finish.

Comment: I did this. However, i received the error that i posted. Thanks for the help anyway